# Shell Script cleanup not returning proper response

Tags: shell

I am trying to run a bash script that will execute my protractor tests and then after run a cleanup method. I have looked at some solutions online and haven't been able to get it working as expected. Even if all the tests pass it still returns a failed message.

```
 #! /bin/bash

cleanup() {
 stops docker container
 echo "Caught SIGTERM signal!"
 kill -TERM "$child" 2>/dev/null
}

trap cleanup SIGTERM

starts docker containers 

exec "$@" &

child=$!

wait "$child"

cleanup
```

What is the proper way to do catch the error response for the exec command and return that as the status of the script? Is there a better way to go about doing it?

Comment: You have scripts/functions in your path named `starts` and `stops`?